Getting a pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Column 1 named type expected length 44 but got length 21 when trying to create Hugging Face database
I am getting the below error when trying to modify, chunk and resave a Huggingface Dataset.
I was wondering if anyone might be able to help?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\conno\LegalAIDataset\LegalAIDataset\main.py", line 39, in <module>
    new_dataset = dataset.map(process_row, batched=True, batch_size=1, remove_columns=None)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\conno\LegalAIDataset\LegalAIDataset\.venv\Lib\site-packages\datasets\arrow_dataset.py", line 602, in wrapper
    out: Union["Dataset", "DatasetDict"] = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\conno\LegalAIDataset\LegalAIDataset\.venv\Lib\site-packages\datasets\arrow_dataset.py", line 567, in wrapper
    out: Union["Dataset", "DatasetDict"] = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\conno\LegalAIDataset\LegalAIDataset\.venv\Lib\site-packages\datasets\arrow_dataset.py", line 3156, in map
    for rank, done, content in Dataset._map_single(**dataset_kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\conno\LegalAIDataset\LegalAIDataset\.venv\Lib\site-packages\datasets\arrow_dataset.py", line 3570, in _map_single
    writer.write_batch(batch)
  File "C:\Users\conno\LegalAIDataset\LegalAIDataset\.venv\Lib\site-packages\datasets\arrow_writer.py", line 571, in write_batch
    pa_table = pa.Table.from_arrays(arrays, schema=schema)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pyarrow\\table.pxi", line 4642, in pyarrow.lib.Table.from_arrays
  File "pyarrow\\table.pxi", line 3922, in pyarrow.lib.Table.validate
  File "pyarrow\\error.pxi", line 91, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Column 1 named type expected length 44 but got length 21

My minimun reproducable code is below:
import datasets
from datasets import load_dataset, Dataset
from semantic_text_splitter import TextSplitter


# Step 1: Load the existing dataset
dataset = load_dataset('HF_Dataset')
# Slice the 'train' split of the dataset
sliced_data = dataset['train'][:100]

# Convert the sliced data back into a Dataset object
dataset = Dataset.from_dict(sliced_data)


def chunk_text(text_list, metadata):
    splitter = TextSplitter(1000)
    chunks = [chunk for text in text_list for chunk in splitter.chunks(text)]
    return {"text_chunks": chunks, **metadata}
# Define a global executor
#executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)

def process_row(batch):
    # Initialize a dictionary to store the results
    results = {k: [] for k in batch.keys()}
    results['text_chunks'] = []  # Add 'text_chunks' key to the results dictionary

    # Process each row in the batch
    for i in range(len(batch['text'])):
        # Apply the chunk_text function to the text
        chunks = chunk_text(batch['text'][i], {k: v[i] for k, v in batch.items() if k != 'text'})
        # Add the results to the dictionary
        for k, v in chunks.items():
            results[k].extend(v)

    # Return the results
    return results

# Apply the function to the dataset
new_dataset = dataset.map(process_row, batched=True, batch_size=1, remove_columns=None)

# Save and upload the new dataset
new_dataset.to_json('dataset.jsonl')
dataset_dict = datasets.DatasetDict({"split": new_dataset})


# dataset_dict.save_to_disk("", format="json")
# dataset_dict.upload_to_hub("", "This is a test dataset")


I was expecting the code to chunk the dataset, keep the metadata and save it as a .jsonl file.
Instead, I got the above error.

If anyone else has this issue, I managed to fix it.
Please see below for my working code.
def process_row(batch):
    # Initialize lists to store the processed rows
    processed_texts = []
    processed_metadata = {k: [] for k, v in batch.items() if k != 'text'}

    # Process each row in the batch
    for i in range(len(batch['text'])):
        # Apply the chunk_text function to the text
        text = batch['text'][i]
        metadata = {k: v[i] for k, v in batch.items() if k != 'text'}
        chunks = chunk_text([text], metadata)['text_chunks']

        # For each chunk, add it to the processed_texts and replicate the metadata
        for chunk in chunks:
            processed_texts.append(chunk)
            for k in processed_metadata:
                processed_metadata[k].append(metadata[k])

    # Combine processed texts and metadata into a single dictionary
    results = {'text': processed_texts}
    for k, v in processed_metadata.items():
        results[k] = v

    return results


No changes to the file loaded?
